# Setting a default editor in Pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, editing, pry

I'm asking about setting a default editor for Pry to use. I'm working on a Rails 
 app. I created a  file named ".pryrc" immediately inside my working directory. 
 In this file, I wrote this line of code (based on what I read on [Github](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Editor-integration) :

```
Pry.config.editor = proc { |file, line| "sublime +#{line} #{file}" }
```

This doesn't seem to work. when I try the command ".sublime company.rb", I 'd get 
 this error:

```
 Error: there was a problem executing system command: sublime company.rb
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Isn't sublime's command line launcher called `subl`?

Comment: oh That's right. i d get the same error anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Change the configuration to:

```
Pry.config.editor = proc { |file, line| "sublime #{file}:#{line}" }
```

You start the editor in Pry by using the **edit** command.

For example to open test.rb at line 30 use:

```
edit test.rb:30
```

See [here](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Editor-integration) for more details

Comment: I thought that d not be directly related. Anyway, I tried that too and this is the error i get:                                                       
[4] pry(main)> edit company.rb:10
Error: `sublime +10 /Users/samira/Desktop/loyal_bank/company.rb` gave exit status: 127

Comment: @Sarah: well, it seems to be a problem with your sublime, not pry editor.

Comment: I think u r right. coz jus now, I tried to open a file with "sublime fileName" even outside Pry. but it says "command not found".

Comment: @sarah you will need to either add the sublime to your path or use the full path in the Pry configuration

Comment: @PaulColeman, Thank u. ur suggestion led me to this [link] (gist.github.com/adrianorsouza/df4759b0583dcd112da4) . Having read this, found the solution. I chose to add sublime to my path and keep .pryrc as it is.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem as mine.Perhaps, you have trouble launching the editor even outside Pry. First thing, make sure to check if the sublime command exists in ur PATH. if not, you probably need to create a symlink between the command and the corresponding path to your app within /usr/local/bin. For more information, see [here](https://gist.github.com/adrianorsouza/df4759b0583dcd112da4).